# Path of Mettle and Aragorn, Hornburg Hero

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was wondering, if [Path of Mettle](https://scryfall.com/card/rix/165/path-of-mettle-metzali-tower-of-triumph) transformed into the "Tower-side" if I controlled [Aragorn, Hornburg Hero](https://scryfall.com/card/ltc/492/aragorn-hornburg-hero) and attacked with at least two creatures.

Walking this through step by step is like:

- in the declare attackers step I declare at least two creatures to attack an opponent
- Once I'm done declaring attackers, those gain First Strike and Renown as a state based action, since Aragorn has a static ability, and no triggered ability (e.g. "whenever a creature you control attacks, it gains")
- After statebased actions are checked, the active player gains priority and triggered abilities are put on the stack. Since I control two attacking creatures with First Strike, the transform-trigger of Path of Mettle is placed on the stack

Does this play out as described, or did I go wrong?

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/56423/if-an-action-causes-a-creature-to-gain-an-ability-does-it-trigger-effects-that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Path of Mettle will transform. It's pretty tricky though.

> 508.1. First, the active player declares attackers.
>
> > 508.1a The active player chooses which creatures that they control, if any, will attack.
> > 508.1k Each chosen creature still controlled by the active player becomes an attacking creature.

In your case, "becomes an attacking creature" may as well read "gains first strike" due to the continuous ability.

> 508.1m Any abilities that trigger on attackers being declared trigger.

The entire process is referred to as "declaring an attacker". That means that this rule:

> 508.2a Abilities that trigger on a creature attacking trigger only at the point the creature is declared as an attacker. They will not trigger if a creature attacks and then that creature’s characteristics change to match the ability’s trigger condition.

refers to the point when you have completed all of 508.1. I believe if that rule said "only at the point the creature is **chosen** as an attacker" instead, then the ruling would be the opposite; because it would mean that the creature would have to fulfil the condition when you get to 508.1a, instead of just when you get to the end of 508.1.